# How to change selection color in SplitView pane UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need some help from you.
I'm developing a UWP app. Right now I'm working on the hamburger menu and when I select a menu item it's marked with [system accent color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UMx1.png). And I want to make selection style like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUuih.png) - a small rectangle near the menu item or at least change the selection color. But unfortunately, there's literally no information that can help me. Neither on StackOverflow nor somewhere else.
So, please help me. And thanks in advance.
Here's a piece of my code:

```
<SplitView Name="menu" Grid.Row="1" OpenPaneLength="250" CompactPaneLength="50" DisplayMode="CompactInline" PaneClosed="menu_PaneClosed">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <RelativePanel>
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="homeMenu" IsSelected="True">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemIcon}" Text="&#xE10F;"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}" Text="Home"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="gamingMenu">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemIcon}" Text="&#xE7FC;"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"  Text="Gaming"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="historyMenu">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemIcon}" Text="&#xE81C;"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"  Text="History"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="likedMenu">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemIcon}" Text="&#xE19F;"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"  Text="Liked videos"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="watchLaterMenu">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemIcon}" Text="&#xE121;"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"  Text="Watch later"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </RelativePanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="content"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you could use `ListView` control instead of ListBox. You would get the same effect. Then you edit the [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx). You could see there's a `SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"` in it. You could change it which you want.

For example,

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter
      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
      SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
      CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
      CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
      DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
      FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
      FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
      PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
      PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
      SelectedBackground="Red"
      SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
      SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
      PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
      SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
      DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
      DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
      ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
      ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
      CheckMode="Inline"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

```xml
<SplitView Name="menu" Grid.Row="1" OpenPaneLength="250" CompactPaneLength="50" DisplayMode="CompactInline">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <RelativePanel>
            <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle1}">
                <ListViewItem  Name="homeMenu">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  Text="&#xE10F;"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Home"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Name="gamingMenu">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  Text="&#xE7FC;"/>
                        <TextBlock  Text="Gaming"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Name="historyMenu">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  Text="&#xE81C;"/>
                        <TextBlock   Text="History"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Name="likedMenu">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  Text="&#xE19F;"/>
                        <TextBlock   Text="Liked videos"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Name="watchLaterMenu">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  Text="&#xE121;"/>
                        <TextBlock   Text="Watch later"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </RelativePanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Frame Name="content"/>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Comment: Thanks. And what do you think about highlighting with rectangle?